# Does innodb_buffer_pool_size setting affect update queries?

Tags: mariadb, innodb, memory

I have a ***huge*** database(16GB) to which I wish to add a new column based on an existing column.

The existing column looks like this:-

```
MariaDB [demo]> SELECT my_mon FROM mytable;
+----------+
| my_mon   |
+----------+
| Jan 2020 |
| Feb 2020 |
| Mar 2020 |
| Apr 2020 |
| May 2020 |
| Jun 2020 |
| Jul 2020 |
| Aug 2020 |
| Sep 2020 |
| Oct 2020 |
| Nov 2020 |
| Dec 2020 |
| Jan 2021 |
| Feb 2021 |
| Mar 2021 |
| Apr 2021 |
| May 2021 |
| Jun 2021 |
| Jul 2021 |
| Aug 2021 |
| Sep 2021 |
| Oct 2021 |
| Nov 2021 |
| Dec 2021 |
+----------+
24 rows in set (0.015 sec)

MariaDB [demo]>
```

I wish to create a new column by doing :

```
MariaDB [demo]> alter table mytable add column my_wave char(8);

MariaDB [demo]> update mytable set my_wave = concat("W",ceiling(month(str_to_date(substr(my_mon,1,3),"%b"))/4)," ",substr(my_mon,5,8));
```

This new column looks like this:

```
MariaDB [demo]> select * from mytable;
+----+----------+---------+
| id | my_mon   | my_wave |
+----+----------+---------+
|  1 | Jan 2020 | W1 2020 |
|  2 | Feb 2020 | W1 2020 |
|  3 | Mar 2020 | W1 2020 |
|  4 | Apr 2020 | W1 2020 |
|  5 | May 2020 | W2 2020 |
|  6 | Jun 2020 | W2 2020 |
|  7 | Jul 2020 | W2 2020 |
|  8 | Aug 2020 | W2 2020 |
|  9 | Sep 2020 | W3 2020 |
| 10 | Oct 2020 | W3 2020 |
| 11 | Nov 2020 | W3 2020 |
| 12 | Dec 2020 | W3 2020 |
| 13 | Jan 2021 | W1 2021 |
| 14 | Feb 2021 | W1 2021 |
| 15 | Mar 2021 | W1 2021 |
| 16 | Apr 2021 | W1 2021 |
| 17 | May 2021 | W2 2021 |
| 18 | Jun 2021 | W2 2021 |
| 19 | Jul 2021 | W2 2021 |
| 20 | Aug 2021 | W2 2021 |
| 21 | Sep 2021 | W3 2021 |
| 22 | Oct 2021 | W3 2021 |
| 23 | Nov 2021 | W3 2021 |
| 24 | Dec 2021 | W3 2021 |
+----+----------+---------+
24 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [demo]>
```

My query is: Will increasing the innodb_buffer_pool_size make this and similar queries run faster ?

I have a total of 8GB of RAM.

My current (default setting I think) is :

| innodb_buffer_pool_size                     | 134217728              |

which is 128MB.

I would like to clarify my query.

The innodb_buffer_pool_size is a ***CACHE***.
A big value for this will ensure that ***multiple reads*** especially ***repeated requests for the same data*** will be ***fast***.

In my case I am doing an ***update***(that is why I described my update at the beginning of this question), which means I need to ***read*** one column and ***write once*** to another column.

Will the innodb_buffer_pool_size be ***relevant*** to the ***update***?

Does ***updating the table*** happen "chunk" by "chunk" of rows, or does it load the table into memory and then update it ?

Perhaps, I would like to see the code/algorithm for the UPDATE.

Can someone clarify ***if*** and ***why*** this setting would affect this ***update*** query?

Note: I am trying to modify the innodb_buffer_pool_size to see if it affects the update time as suggested by Ergest Basha.

My original server was ***LIVE DEVELOPMENT*** server so I am trying to run this experiment on my laptop. I created a  3GB dataset. My innodb_buffer_pool_size on this computer is also the ***same***. I have not ***yet*** modified it.

```
MariaDB [demo]> show variables like "%innodb_buffer_pool_size%";
+-------------------------+-----------+
| Variable_name           | Value     |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| innodb_buffer_pool_size | 134217728 |
+-------------------------+-----------+
1 row in set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [demo]> LOAD DATA INFILE './mydata.csv'  INTO TABLE mytable  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS; 
Query OK, 132000000 rows affected (56 min 11.379 sec)
Records: 132000000  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [demo]> ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN my_wave CHAR(7);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (1.650 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [demo]> UPDATE mytable SET my_wave=concat("W",ceiling(month(str_to_date(substr(my_mon,1,3),"%b"))/4)," ",substr(my_mon,5,8));
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

MariaDB [demo]> UPDATE mytable SET my_wave=concat("W",ceiling(month(str_to_date(substr(my_mon,1,3),"%b"))/4)," ",substr(my_mon,5,8));
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    36
Current database: demo

ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

$ systemctl status mysql
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.31 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-02-06 14:56:15 IST; 12s ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
  Process: 28797 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28798 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28800 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ $? -eq 0 ]  
  Process: 28970 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 28972 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 28848 (mysqld)
   Status: "To roll back: 1 transactions, 11705889 rows"
    Tasks: 32 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 440.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           └─28848 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Restarted the server but the query still does not go through.

```
MariaDB [demo]> UPDATE mytable SET my_wave=concat("W",ceiling(month(str_to_date(substr(my_mon,1,3),"%b"))/4)," ",substr(my_mon,5,8));
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
MariaDB [demo]>
```

Hi again,

When I set the innodb_buffer_pool_size=5G

and try to run the UPDATE to create a new column, it ***froze*** my laptop.

I restarted my computer and now my mysql refuses to start.

```
$ sudo mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Comment: @ErgestBasha please see my edit. The links you have posted talk about innodb_buffer_pool_size in ***general***. My query is about this variable affecting this particular query.

Comment: You could add it as a [virtual column](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/). The buffer pool also stores the MVCC history and provides a breathing room for the purging to disk of changes. In general, recommend storing a date in a date format and handle the representation changes in the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly.

128M is an old, too-small, default value for that setting.  Change to about 70% of available memory, which might be:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 5G
```

Because it is a "cache", a bigger value will cut down on I/O, which is a big part of any big query on a big table.

`UPDATEing` a 16GB table will be quite slow, but for another reason.  The system will keep an old copy of all the rows in case you crash.  (That way it can recover the data back to consistent state.)

That is, the `UPDATE` will take a long time, regardless of the cache size.

All actions on all tables do use the buffer_pool.

`UPDATE` will not chunk by itself.  You can do the chunking.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks .  (It is written in a `DELETE` context, but the changes for `UPDATE` should be easy.)

Another approach to consider:  Build a new table with the old column(s) plus the new column(s), such as

```
CREATE TABLE newtable (
    id ...,
    my_mon ...,
    my_wave ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
    SELECT id, my_mon, concat(...) AS my_wave;
```